# How can I screw progressbar to copy files

Tags: python

There is a progressbar.

```
self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Dialog)
self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 651, 23))
self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
```

There is a copy function

```
shutil.copytree(cur_dir + "/321321", cur_dir + "/folder2")
```

How to make progressbar increase based on the remaining copy time?

Also interested in the archive

```
shutil.make_archive("test archive", "zip", src)
```

Comment: By the looks of it you'll have to do some maths. I was hoping to see shutil have some kind of file transferred event but alas nothing stands out in the docs. Basically you'll need to figure out file size, file numbers, and transfer speed from one location to the other (taking into consideration across networks or hard drives as well).

Comment: @D.Foley yes, I think need to override the copytree method

Comment: If you just want to give the user some form of feedback then maybe it would be a better idea to have your own collection of files to copy and call copy2() on each individual file. After the file is copied just update the progress bar. Could also pass a function to copy_function in copytree()

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for zipping folders only !

and it's not that bad :)

```
import shutil
import threading
import os

class Fake_logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = ''

    def info(self, s, *args):
        if args:
            self.path = args[0]

    def debug(self, s, *args):
        pass

def folder_size(folder_path):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            # skip if it is symbolic link
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size

logger = Fake_logger()
zipThread = threading.Thread(target= shutil.make_archive, args= (writeFolder_path, 'zip' ,readFolder_path), kwargs = {'logger':logger})
zipThread.start()

Last_path = logger.path
allsize = folder_size(readFolder_path)
size = 0
while zipThread.is_alive():
    if logger.path != Last_path:
        if os.path.isfile(readFolder_path+'\\'+Last_path):
            size+= os.path.getsize(readFolder_path+'\\'+Last_path)
            print(size/allsize*100) # <-- Your Progressbar Value %0-100
        Last_path = logger.path
print(100)
```